# Casting to multiple datatype in SELECT doesn't get expected result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I have a table A with columns: ColumnName, Minimum, Maximum, and DataType.

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    ColumnName varchar(50),
    Maximum decimal(38, 5),
    Minimum decimal(38, 5),
    DataType varchar(10)
);
```

They store values as exactly as their column name labels. They store column names of another table, table B, minimum value of that column, maximum value of that column, and data type of that column.

I am trying to get results in their respective data type.

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT 
    ColumnName,
    'Minimum' = 
        CASE
            WHEN DataType = 'int' THEN CAST(Minimum AS INT)
            WHEN DataType ='decimal' THEN CAST(Minimum AS DECIMAL(38, 4))
        END,
    Maximum,
    DataType
FROM A;
```

What I get is every row is cast to `DECIMAL(38, 4)`.

Comment: Well yes, a case expression can only return a single datatype. And a column in a query can only have a single datatype...

Comment: Cast again as varchar perhaps , though I don't see why you would want to do this.

Comment: @DaleK so the selected column casts the output column to the datatype that conforms with all the rows?

Comment: @P.Salmon casting as varchar will retain the 0's from the original datatype decimal(38, 5)

Comment: You can checkout sql_variant which handles this stuff. BUT, it's probably not what you want to do anyway. Every "column" in sql has a single datatype usually, so it's pointless to do what you want to do. There's no getColumnType(rowid, colid) methods in either jdbc or ODBC. You should let the server upcast your data to the "biggest" data type and handle whatever you need to handle in the application

Comment: @francios_de_jarjeyes what you try to do won't work in any database. In the relational model a table specifies the relation between the values in a row, it's not a spreadsheet. The query engine must know the type of the values when it compiles the query itself. That type will be used to generate an execution plan. In SQL Server only you could use the `sql_variant` type instead of `decimal` BUT that passes the cast operation to the client. Another option could be to have different range columns per type

Comment: What are you trying to do with this table anyway? It does matter. Database engines already keep data statistics per column. They won't be perfectly accurate but they may be good enough. If you want this for *reporting*, a separate reporting database will be preferable. If it is for data profiling, you probably shouldn't store the results in the database. SSIS itself has a [data profiling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/data-profiling-task-and-viewer?view=sql-server-ver16) task and viewer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's more of a exercise problem involving data profiling. I will look into SSIS data profiling task and viewer, thank you.

Comment: You could trim to remove trailing 0 eg https://dbfiddle.uk/dc1PWCfv

Comment: @francios_de_jarjeyes there are a lot of tools for data profiling, including SSIS's own task,  and various libraries in Python. For example, the [describe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) method of a Pandas dataframe will return multiple statistics for every numeric column. Try using Pandas in a VS Code Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    ColumnName,
    'Minimum' = FORMAT(Minimum, 
        CASE
            WHEN DataType = 'int' THEN 'N0'
            WHEN DataType ='decimal' THEN 'N2'
        END)
    Maximum,
    DataType
FROM A;
```

The other way would be to apply a different format but on the application side, either using DisplayFormat or DisplayFormatString or something similar.